# What is the structure of Libvirt Qemu VM dump/save files?

Tags: memory, kvm, qemu, dump

I need to do some exploration of Qemu-KVM virtual machines physical memory (particularly I need to check the fact of the physical memory intersection). In order to do that I'm trying to save VM's state with a `virsh dump` or `virsh save` command.

The dumped files have binary structure, and I cannot find a description for that, exepting this [unofficial(?) tool](https://github.com/juergh/lqs2mem). It is told there that `virsh dump` creates file of *QEMU-savevm format* while `virsh save` gives a Libvirt-QEMU-save formatted file. However, I didn't manage to find these terms on the Internet.

I'll be glad if someone could clarify this situation, maybe giving a link to the mislaid documents. Thank you,

Comment: have you tried asking the developers? they monitor IRC and the mailing lists